# Run async\await infinitely

Tags: javascript, for-loop, async-await

I want to iterate over the playlist array asynchronously and endlessly.
But the only loop that works with async\await is for..of loop which I can't figure out how to make infinite.

```
   async function playback(playlist) {
        for (const item of playlist) {
        await play(item);
        console.log('finished waiting for ' + item.name);                  
    }
```

Comment: `while (true)`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a [for without a condition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Loops_and_iteration#for_statement), to make it infinite, and the modulo operator [`%`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#Remainder) to loop through the playlist items in a circular fashion:

```
async function playback(playlist) {
  for (let i = 0;; i = (i + 1) % playlist.length) {
    const item = playlist[i];
    await play(item);
    console.log('finished waiting for ' + item.name);  
  }                
}
```

Comment: I'd rather do `i = (i + 1) % playlist.length` as the increment and use only `i` in the loop body though

Comment: I agree, @Bergi. It would also avoid overflow issues. I have edited my answer. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 0):

> But the only loop that works with async\await is for..of loop

Nope. You can use `await` everywhere inside `async function`s, also inside of `while` or `for` loops.

```
 async function playback(playlist) {
   while(true) {
    for (const item of playlist) {
      await play(item);                   
    }
  }
}
```